# How to I search location data in Firebase?

Tags: php, search, firebase

I have data structured as :

```
properties : 
    unique-property-id :
        lat: 41.032, 
        lng: 28.9832
    another-unique-property-id:
        lat: another-lat,
        lng: another-lng
```

How can I search these properties as between max_lat and min_lat and between max_lng and min_lng ?

I am using [firebase-php](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php)

Do I have to download all the data and do a search on php side?

Comment: Firebase can only order/filter a single property. Luckily there's a [library called Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire/) that combines latitude and longitude into a single value (called a Geohash) and then can use those for filtering. The link above provides information about that library, which is available for JavaScript, Android and iOS. There is no PHP version of the library though, so you'll have to figure out how to deal with that hurdle yourself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209469/handling-geocoding-in-firebase