# Firebase query is not returning any results from the database

Tags: firebase

I am trying a simple search in Firebase to return data from my Firebase data but nothing returns.

JSON STRUCTURE

```
{
    "-JZQzhqTI6NUQMfgHwQc" : {
        "Divisions" : {
            "-JZLh2UYKi5IvphLtX4I" : true,
            "-JZLh2Uc5HhffF1ki4H1" : true
        },
        "SportTypes" : {
            "-JZLOh7KtM78I5wAL6Ua" : true
        },
        "name" : "winnipegjets",
        "nickname" : "Jets",
        "teamname" : "Winnipeg Jets"
    }
}
```

My Firebase code to do a search is the following

```
   new Firebase("https://sizzling-fire-6197.firebaseio.com/teams")
            .startAt('Winnipeg Jets')
            .endAt('Winnipeg Jets')
            .once('value', function(snap) {
                console.log('matching team is', snap.val())
            });
```

But once the code is execute it returns null.  Also is there a way to search a specific field.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272919/how-to-query-firebase-for-property-with-specific-value-inside-all-children, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812624/firebase-where-like-search, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587775/database-style-queries-with-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963776/get-users-by-name-property-using-firebase and probably quite a few others.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a collection of teams, the first one is in a node named `-JZQzhqTI6NUQMfgHwQc` (which was probably generated by calling `push`). It has a property `name` with a value of `winnipegjets` and a property `teamname` with a value of `Winnipeg Jets`.

In a [Firebase query you can filter nodes in two ways](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries):

- by their name
- by their priority

Your node is named `-JZQzhqTI6NUQMfgHwQc` and it has a priority (that is not shown in the JSON you posted). Those are the only two values you can filter by.

If you're not using the priority yet, you might consider setting the `name` or `teamname` as the priority (look at the documentation for `setPriority`) and filter on that.

It also looks like you are already trying to make the `name` property unique. In that case, you could consider creating the structure as follows:

```
{
    "winnipegjets" : {
        "Divisions" : {
            "-JZLh2UYKi5IvphLtX4I" : true,
            "-JZLh2Uc5HhffF1ki4H1" : true
        },
        "SportTypes" : {
            "-JZLOh7KtM78I5wAL6Ua" : true
        },
        "nickname" : "Jets",
        "teamname" : "Winnipeg Jets"
    }
}
```

Code for that would be something like:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://sizzling-fire-6197.firebaseio.com/teams');
ref.child('winnipegjets').set(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting priority. Then you need to orderByChild, inorder for the [firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html) to return result. In your case:

```
new Firebase("https://sizzling-fire-6197.firebaseio.com/teams")
            .orderByChild('teamname')
            .startAt('Winnipeg Jets')
            .endAt('Winnipeg Jets')
            .once('value', function(snap) {
                console.log('matching team is', snap.val())
            });
```