# Firebase Authentication Service - lookup uid from email without login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am building an app using Firebase, Firebase's Authentication Service (simple email/password login), and storing user information in a manner pretty similar to what is described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

Part of my functionality will need to allow looking up another user based on an email address.

Is there a straightforward way to use an email to lookup the Firebase defined uid (i.e. 'simpleLogin:9') without having to iterate over all users, or being able to actually log them in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `users` node is just a regular node in Firebase. So the only way to look up items is either by the name of the node or by the priority of the node.

If you want to stick to using the `uid` as the node name, you can set the email address as the priority using `setPriority` or `setWithPriority` and then filter using `startAt` and `endAt`.

```
  // save new user's profile into Firebase so we can
  // list users, use them in security rules, and show profiles
  myRef.child('users').child(user.uid).setWithPriority({
    displayName: user.displayName,
    provider: user.provider,
    provider_id: user.id
  }, user.email);

  var userRef = myRef.child('users').startAt(user.email).endAt(user.email);
```

But if you're only using simple email, you might consider simply storing the users by their email address to begin with:

```
  myRef.child('users').child(user.email).set({
    displayName: user.displayName,
    provider: user.provider,
    provider_id: user.id
  });

  var userRef = myRef.child('users').child(user.email);
```

See also:

- [Database-style Queries with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587775/database-style-queries-with-firebase)
- [How to query firebase for property with specific value inside all children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272919/how-to-query-firebase-for-property-with-specific-value-inside-all-children)
- Top results from Googling "Firebase where query".

Comment: Ahh thank you, I haven't read much on querying and I had this idea that I was going to have to write code that read manually read through all users.  That makes much more sense.  Now that I know more about what I needed to search for, I ran across this blog entry - https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#byemail

Comment: Yeah, that blog post is pretty much mandatory reading when you start working with Firebase. I updated my answer to include some code snippets.

Comment: I tried to use email as the name of the node, but it says it cannot support to store dots "." and all of the emails have them. How do you recommend to store it @FrankvanPuffelen?

Comment: Most developers replace the `.` with a `,`. But any escaping will likely do.