# Firebase Authentication : Lookup a user by Email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using [Firebase Authentication with Email and Password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth)

I would like to know if i can 'lookup' a user by email only while also not being signed in as a user

The reason I'd like to do this is, is to simply identify if I am already a user of the system, using an email address only

I looked at [this older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019279/firebase-authentication-service-lookup-uid-from-email-without-login) but it appears to be the previous version of Firebase

Is it possible to do this in the current Firebase, or my alternative would be to keep this information available (and open to all?) to find out if a given email is part of my system?

Comment: There is no built-in API in Firebase Authentication to look up a user by their email address. The common approach developers take is to solve this by modeling the information they need in the Firebase Database as in the thread you linked.

Comment: Thanks! If i maintain a node of user email addresses to simply get a Boolean True or False for existence, how do I protect this from not being read by anyone (public/world)?

Comment: You cannot prevent lookup of an individual email address, since that is exactly the use-case you're trying to implement. But you can make the list unreadable and only each individual email address readable to minimize exposure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen would not the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail method work here? If so, how does one use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new method of creating users with email password returns a value whether the given email address is already in use. See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Yup this is just what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I use fetchProvidersForEmail(email)
and if the result return as empty array then, this email hasn't been use to sign up.

```js
firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(email)
.then(providers => {
  if (providers.length === 0) {
    // this email hasn't signed up yet
  } else {
    // has signed up
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that the method is now called fetchSignInMethodsForEmail

Answer (score 7):

You can look up user information by email:

```js
firebase.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

I'd like to make things more clear that this method does not exist — one could be looking for it in the firebase client library, in which it has never been available in the first place and it wouldn't be a good idea to have anyway. This method is part of the admin SDK, so in order to call the method, you need to run it on the server, and invoke it from the client. OP didn't scope the question to firebase client library, so my answer is still correct.

[Retrieve user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data)

Comment: The returned object's documentation can be found [on the UserRecord reference documentation from firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/UserRecord)

Comment: This API does not exists [anymore].

Comment: @SalathielGenèse Where did you find mention to the API deprecation? I can still see it referenced here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.BaseAuth#getuserbyemail and documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data

Comment: Sorry @Andrea, you just called to my attention that JS vs. Dart SDK APIs differs with subtleties. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

import { fetchSignInMethodsForEmail } from 'firebase/auth'

```
fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, registerEamil).then((result) =>{
        console.log("result", result);
        if (result.length === 0) {
            Navigate("/authentication/select_role/" + 
      registerEamil)
        } else {
            Navigate('/')
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side option:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/lookup

POST [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{targetProjectId}/accounts:lookup](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7BtargetProjectId%7D/accounts:lookup)

```
{ "email": ["rodneydangerfield@stackoverflow.kom"] }
```

Answer (score -2):

As for today 2021 Nov. 18th, there is no way provided by the Firebase SDK to fetch a user by email.

Comment: The method from these answers still applies, however how you access it in v9 onwards has changed: [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#fetchsigninmethodsforemail)

Comment: This API tells us which providers can a user signs-in with... Not the user account infos, like, for name one, his profile URL.